# preg_match_all returning an error undefined offset

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am using preg_match_all and its returning this error :

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in B:\xampp\htdocs\fogsy\link_searcher.php on line 98
```

and this is line 98:

```
$server_name=$matches[0][1]."/";
```

here is my function:
it's Used to retrieve links from html body.

```
    function GetLinks($body_str,$parent_url)
        {           
            $url_list=array();

            preg_match_all('/http:\/\/(.*)\//iU', $parent_url, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
            $server_name=$matches[0][1]."/";

            preg_match_all('/< *a.*href *= *[\'"](.*)[\'"].*>(.*)< *\/a *>/iU', $body_str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

            for($count=0;$count<count($matches);$count++)
                {
                    $text=$matches[$count][2];

                    if(strpos(strtolower($matches[$count][1]),"http://")===false&&strpos(strtolower($matches[$count][1]),"www")===false)
                    $href="http://".$server_name.trim($matches[$count][1],"/");                         
                    else $href=$matches[$count][1];                             

                    $url_list[$text."_".$count]=$href;  
                }   
            return $url_list;
        }
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is becuase you dont have a index 0 here : `$server_name=$matches[0][1]."/";`

print_r($matches); and see.

It occurs because there is not matching pattern in  `$parent_url`

Change it like this :

```
if(count($matches) > 0){
    $server_name=$matches[0][1]."/";
}
else{
    $server_name="";
}
```

But this will affect your other functionality, better send a well formed `$parent_url` to this function.